# MPI: Sending a non-contiguous part of an array of objects with arbitrary sized vectors

Tags: c++, vector, types, mpi, derived-types

I'm trying to learn MPI and am trying to develop a C++ program where I need to send a bunch of objects with arbitrary sized vectors.

Let the class be defined as

```
class MyClass
{
    int id;
    int a[3];
    vector<int> b;
}
```

I'm able to use `MPI_Type_create_struct` along with `MPI_Type_create_resized` in order to send one object from rank 0 to rank 1 as such:

```
int size = 5;
b.resize(size);
MPI_Datatype mytype;
inr lengths[3] = {1,3,size};
MPI_Aint disp[3];
MyClass obj;
MPI_Aint base, lb, extent;

MPI_Get_address(&obj, &base);
MPI_Get_address(&obj.id, &disp[0]);
MPI_Get_address(&obj.a, &disp[1]);
MPI_Get_address(&obj.b, &disp[2]);

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   disp[i] = MPI_Aint_diff(disp[i], base);

MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
MPI_Type_create_struct(4, lengths, disp, types, &mytype);
MPI_Type_get_extent(mytype, &lb, &extent);
MPI_Type_create_resized(mytype, lb, sizeof(MYClass), &mytype);
MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);
```

Now, If I have an array of objects  `MyClass obj_arr[10]` and I want to send a non-contiguous part of this array, I'm able to achieve this using `MPI_Type_create_indexed_block`. This of course works only if the size of the vector (`size`) is constant across all the objects. The problem is in my case, the size is not uniform across all the objects. I'm not sure what the right approach here is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current solution is to create a custom MPI Datatype for each indivdiual object, and send it to the appropriate rank. This would remove the need for `MPI_Type_create_indexed_block`, but I'm guessing this approach would be very inefficient due to the potentially large number of datatype creations and sends/recvs. Since I'm new to MPI, I'm wondering if there is a better solution using a different approach I'm not aware of?

Comment: I do not think your current code is even correct. `vector<int>` likely contains some metadata (e.g. length) but you are only transferring the `int` that populates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C++ vector is a small block, containing the size, and the address of the actual data. So with

```
MPI_Get_address(&obj.b, &disp[2]);
```

you get the address of that small block. Instead you should get the address of `obj.b.data()`.

Next, you can not do this with an `MPI_Type_Struct` because the data of `MyClass` that you want to send is not contiguous. You could use `MPI_Pack` to pack the `id,a` and actual vector elements, plus an int describing how many elements needs to be unpacked at the other side.

Finally, `create_resized` is the wrong tool here. Don't use that in this case.

Comment: Don't you need at the very least to also pack the vector length so it can be allocated on the receiver?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Goes without saying. But I'll say it anyway.

Comment: I was not aware of ``MPI_Pack``. Thanks for the help @VictorEijkhout and @ GillesGouaillardet